# problem using label text as part of my gridview header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Sorry I am filled with errors today

```
Parser Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'ItemTemplate' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.

    Source Error: 


    Line 66:                            
    Line 67: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AS of" & label2.text>
    Line 68: <ItemTemplate>
    Line 69:  <%#Getsales(Decimal.Parse(Eval("AsOFSales").ToString())).ToString("C0")%>
    Line 70: </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr. TA said, you need to make those changes from your code behind. Something like the code below - just replace the ? in Cells(?) with the (zero based index) of the column number in your grid (or w

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs) handles DataGrid1.ItemDataBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header) Begin
       e.Item.Cells(?).Text = "AS of" & label2.text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: for your method how would i select which column's header is changed, because i want to do this for multiple columns thank you

Comment: Just add more lines like the one e.Item.Cells(?). The first column in your grid is number 0, each one is one higher. If you want to change the value of the rows that are in the header then you need to add an ELSE that evaluates the ItemType and matches ListItemType.AlternatingItem or ListItemType.Item.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have VB.NET code in ASP.NET markup. If you want to change HeaderText, do it in code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
Line 67: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AS of" & label2.text>
```

It would be best to leave it blank and set it in the code behind during the RowDataBound event.

```
Protected Sub myGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles myGridView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        Dim e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "As of " & Label2.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that you don't have sorting enabled on the GridView. If you do have sorting enabled, you will first have to find the LinkButton control and change its text value. I also used the arbitrary value 2 in the Cells identifier. You would need to use the numeric column number for the cell you want.

Comment: thank you for your response, I am just wondering how I could do this for multiple columns. or how do i select which column to change the header for

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - The columns are rendered as an array of cells (in a table). To select the column, you just use the index of the cell within that array. e.Row.Cells(0) is the first cell.